# DOM with SimpleXML Doesnt show the data in XML format in Browser using PHP

Tags: php, dom, simplexml

This is my PHP code  to read XML from a URL using SimpleXML and DOM to change some parameters and show it on a web page

The Feed i am reading is at http://tinyurl.com/boy7mr5

```
<?php

  $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.abc.com');


  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->formatOutput = true;

  $r = $doc->createElement( "All_Products" );
  $doc->appendChild( $r );

  foreach( $xml as $Product)
  {


 $b = $doc->createElement( "Product" );
   $doc->appendChild( $b );

  foreach($Product as $prname=>$value)
  {


  $prname1  = $doc->createElement( $prname );
  $prname1->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode( $value )
  );
  $b->appendChild($prname1);
  if($prname=='ProductName')
  {

  $ProductURL = $doc->createElement( "ProductURL" );
  $ProductURL->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode('http://www.abc.com/'.$Product->ProductName.'-p/'.$Product->ProductCode .'.htm' )
  );
  $b->appendChild( $ProductURL );

  }
  if($prname=='Categories'){

foreach($value as $catname=>$catvalue)
  {
   $c = $doc->createElement( "Category" );
   $doc->appendChild( $c );
  foreach($catvalue as $catname1=>$catvalue1)
  {
 // echo $catname1."==".$catvalue1;
    $catname12 = $doc->createElement( $catname1);
  $catname12 ->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode(htmlspecialchars_decode($catvalue1) )
  );
  $c->appendChild( $catname12);

  }
   $prname1->appendChild( $c );
  }
  }


  }
  $r->appendChild( $b );

  }
  echo $doc->saveXML();

  ?>
```

**The last line prints all the XML as it is but it shows the garbage data as you can see at this url  http://tinyurl.com/bty8286.**

**I want the data to look like this http://tinyurl.com/boy7mr5 in the Browser, what should i change in the code**

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of the `Content-Type` [HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17). The second link uses the `application/xml` while the first one uses php's default `text/html`. You can change your php script's HTTP headers with the [header()](http://fphp.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
header('content-type: application/xml');
```

#### EDIT:

I've been able to fetch the original input, the only the header doesn't made it work (at least in firefox), got parse error on line 48580, this is due no encoding was set to the `DOMDocument` object, while the original input is in utf-8. With

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
```

should work.

Comment: i tried that but its giving me error XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: /feed.php
Line Number 1, Column 3:  
--^

Comment: That probably means that your outputting a non well formed xml string. Most websites html are not valid as xml or maybe a php error lurks in to the output, or other non DomDocument generated output. Try view-sorce in browser to and look around. (a `$doc->formatoutput = true;` can be helpful too.)

Comment: i have already used $doc->formatOutput = true; but still the same issue. The source XML is well formed as you can see here at http://tinyurl.com/boy7mr5

Comment: For me, its simply outputting 2 space chars, while the original feed just returns an empty response, at least at this moment.

Comment: the original feed returns XML

Comment: Yup, now I've been able to fetch it (man its large), edited the answer, this made it work for me in firefox + chromium.